# How to send axhline to back of Matplotlib's barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code. It uses [Matplotlib wrapper in Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test=u"""Cell,Value
Bcells,0.056304
DendriticCells,0.3155388
Macrophages,0.131430
"""

tableau10=[ "#17BECF", "#BCBD22", "#7F7F7F", ]

toplot_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(test))
toplot_df.set_index('Cell',inplace=True)
xlabels =  toplot_df.index.values
barplot   = toplot_df.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(17,17), \
                          color = tableau10, \
                          width=0.7,\
                          fontsize = 30,\
                          legend=False,
                          ylim = (0,0.5),
                          subplots=False)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=30, ha='right')

# How to to make this to the back
plt.axhline(y=0.1, linewidth=1, color='r',zorder=1)
plt.xlabel("")
plt.ylabel("Score", fontsize=30, fontweight="bold")
```

And it makes this figure:

[image]

As stated there. How can I make the `axhline` to the background?
I tried `zorder` but won't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just need to make the `zorder` of the `barplot` higher than the `zorder` of the `axhline`. In your example, I just had to add the option `zorder=2` to the `barplot = toplot_df.plot()` call.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test=u"""Cell,Value
Bcells,0.056304
DendriticCells,0.3155388
Macrophages,0.131430
"""

tableau10=[ "#17BECF", "#BCBD22", "#7F7F7F", ]

toplot_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(test))
toplot_df.set_index('Cell',inplace=True)
xlabels =  toplot_df.index.values
barplot   = toplot_df.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(17,17), \
                          color = tableau10, \
                          width=0.7,\
                          fontsize = 30,\
                          legend=False,
                          ylim = (0,0.5),
                          subplots=False,
                          zorder=2)                         ##### This is all I added

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=30, ha='right')

# How to to make this to the back
plt.axhline(y=0.1, linewidth=1, color='r',zorder=1)
plt.xlabel("")
plt.ylabel("Score", fontsize=30, fontweight="bold")

plt.show()
```

[image]